# Reemplazar archivos en un campo de tipo FileField en Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

En Django, tengo un campo de mi modelo que utiliza `FileField` para cargar archivos.

```
class Documento(models.Model):
    ....
    archivo = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/Documentos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
```

He notado que si se cambia o se carga otro archivo, el anterior permanece en el directorio de destino, por lo tanto, quiero que si yo cargo un nuevo archivo, el que estaba anteriormente se elimine para que únicamente me aparezca el ultimo y así no acumular un montón de archivos innecesarios.

Cómo lo haría?

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo, se puede utilizar las señales (Django signals) `pre_save` y `post_delete`. Para ello se agregar lo siguiente al final de models.py

Para eliminar el archivo si se elimina el objeto

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete, pre_save
...

@receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=Documento)
def auto_delete_file_on_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Elimina el archivo de directorio si se elimina el objeto correspondiente.
    """
    if instance.archivo:
        if os.path.isfile(instance.archivo.path):
            print("path: ", instance.archivo.path)
            os.remove(instance.archivo.path)
```

Para eliminar y/o reemplazar el archivo cuando se actualiza el objeto

```
@receiver(models.signals.pre_save, sender=Documento)
def auto_delete_file_on_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Elimina el archivo antiguo del directorio cuando se actualiza el objeto correspondiente con un nuevo archivo
    """
    if not instance.pk:
        return False

    old_file = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).archivo

    if old_file:
        new_file = instance.archivo
        if not old_file == new_file:
            if os.path.isfile(old_file.path):
                os.remove(old_file.path)
    else:
        pass
```